# String Replace: Ignore Whitespace

Tags: c#, xml, regex, string

The issue that I am having is the following.

The root cause of my issue is "XML" parsing (XML is in quotes, because in this case, it is not directly XML) and whitespace.

I need to be able to convert this:

```
 "This is a <tag>string</tag>"
```

into

```
 "This is a {0}"
```

It must be able to handle nested tags, and that sort of thing.  My plan was to use the following to get my replacement text.

```
 var v = XDocument.Parse(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", myString),LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
 var ns = v.DescendantNodes();
 var n = "" + ns.OfType<XElement>().First(node => node.Name != "root");
```

That code returns the first pair of matching tags.  It can handle nesting, etc.  The only real issue is that even with the "PreserveWhitespace" option, carriage returns are getting eliminated.  `"\r\n"` is converted to just `"\n"`.  This prevents a match, so:

```
 myString = myString.Replace(n,"{0}");
```

does not work as expected.  So I am trying to come up with a way to get the replacement to work properly, ignoring whitespace, but I don't know how to begin...  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Input:

```
string s = "This <tag id=\"1\">string <inner><tag></tag></inner></tag> is <p>inside <b>of</b> another</p> string";
```

#### C# code:

```
Match m;
do
{
  m = Regex.Match(s, @"\A([\s\S]*)(<(\S+)[^[<>]*>[^<>]*</\3>)([\s\S]*)\Z");
  if (m.Success) {
    s = m.Groups[1].Value + "{0}" + m.Groups[4].Value;
    System.Console.WriteLine("Match: " + m.Groups[2].Value);
  }
} while (m.Success);
System.Console.WriteLine("Result: " + s);
```

#### Output:

```
Match: <b>of</b>
Match: <p>inside {0} another</p>
Match: <tag></tag>
Match: <inner>{0}</inner>
Match: <tag id="1">string {0}</tag>
Result: This {0} is {0} string
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/8auRKT)**.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails if the nested tag is of the same type: "This <tag>string <inner><tag></tag></inner></tag> is <p>inside <b>of</b> another</p> string";

Comment: @nosirrahcd - I have updated my answer and a demo link now serves input from your above comment.

Comment: Thanks Omega.  I have approved your answer since it does answer my question, as written.  Is there a good way to capture the value of just the first tag, and replace just the first tag, using that method?  This is for a parser I am modifying, and I need to store "{0}" and then add the text that was replaced to a dictionary in the form of {key=0,value="<tag>...</tag>"}

Comment: Also, this breaks on attributes. (<tag id="1">, etc.)

Comment: @nosirrahcd - I have updated my answer to work with tag parameters and to allow you to "store" matches that were replaced. I am not sure what you mean by *"capture the value of just the first tag"*, as sometimes are tags inside of other tags, so please clarify this in details - let's say what would you expect as output from input that I used in the demo code...

Answer (score 0):

Although not the best solution (if you have just `'\n'` in your `myString`) but it's worth a try:

```
myString =  myString.Replace(n.Replace("\n", "\r\n"), "{0}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a CDATA section ?

```
v = XDocument.Parse(string.Format("<root><![CDATA[{0}]]></root>", myString));
```

Not got anything handy but I suspect you might have to mess about with the selector after it, and get it's child (text node)